# convert one array data to another data with new changes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to convert one data array to another array with new change means, if id match then push data into current one otherwise create new object with second id

```
let finaldata=[]

let data =[{id:1,name:"meet"},{id:2,name:"raj"},{id:1,name:"hari"},{id:3,name:"hari"},{id:2,name:"ram"}]

//I want this below array how can I archive this.?

finaldata= [ { id: 1, names: [ 'meet', 'hari' ] },
  { id: 2, names: [ 'raj', 'ram' ] },
  { id: 3, names: [ 'hari' ] }]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? please post the code you tried

Comment: If you haven't tried anything, then read about groupBy, that should help you understand how to approach this

Answer (score -1):

```
let finaldata = [];
let data =[{id:1,name:"meet"},{id:2,name:"raj"},{id:1,name:"hari"},{id:3,name:"hari"},{id:2,name:"ram"}];

data.forEach((e) => {
    let val = {};
    val.id = e.id;
  val.names = [e.name];

if (finaldata.length > 0) {
  let match = 0;
  
  for(i = 0; i < finaldata.length; i++) {
    if(finaldata[i].id == e.id){
      finaldata[i].names.push(e.name);
      match = 1;
    }
  }
  
  if(match == 0){
  finaldata.push(val);
  }
} else {
    finaldata.push(val);
}

});

console.log(finaldata);
```

Comment: This will not give the exact output that I want this just create first obj into array last two are missing

Comment: It does now, misread your question

Comment: code is not working throw error

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L24jc8pq/1/ ?

Comment: it's working fine in solution